# Can I edit png file with AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, png

If I draw a png based vector image, in inkscape for example and embed it in a AS3 flex project, will I be able to manipulate the elements inside, for example change position or size or whatever, with plain As3 code?

Or is there a way to draw an image and than use the graphics inside with AS3 code?

Comment: Vlad, aren't you confusing PNG and SVG here? Inkscape is a vector graphics editor, using SVG. PNG is a bitmap format.

Comment: Yes, sure I was tallking about vector graphics. Dont now if svg can be embeded in flex project?

Comment: I found this site. Very useful http://www.streamhead.com/how-to-use-vector-graphics-in-flashdevelop-svg-in-flash/ yup it is possible to embed svg in as3 and use it as sprite :) awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by either writing your own code in flex4 or earlier or using a pre-existing library such as http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/

Plus, if using Flex 4.6 you can use the FXG Library here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f26c150d412357de3591-8000.html

Comment: Wow, just read some docs on FXG, it surely is awesome. Its pity that there is no support in programs like inkskape and gimp to export or save FXG file :(

Answer (score 1):

You can change position, size, scale, rotation, distortion, blending modes of images and even crop, redraw and manipulate individual pixel data with AS3 code.

If you're asking whether you could extract vector data from the raster image and manipulate that vector data — no. Though the [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) class has many basic functions for vector drawing and you can find a decent amount of libraries built upon it to offer enhanced functionality.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of libraries for drawing with AS3 code? I fill it quite difficult to use drawPath in Graphics class for complex stuff